# While Condition to cat a file line by line

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, ksh

Typically I use

```
cat filename|while read line; do
echo $line
```

This works fine...but I would like to do this with a condition attached.

```
cat filename|while i=2 read line; do
echo $line
```

Now I know that wont work, but how can I attach a condition to this?

Comment: The correct way to iterate through a file is `while read line; do ...; done < filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final working version..works on HP, SOL & RHEL.

```
cat $NASFILE|while [[ $NFS2 != "Completed" ]] && read line; do
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate the conditions like so:

```
while ((i == 2)) && read line; do
```

Comment: this is tested under ksh93 (Mac OS X, Mountain Lion)

Comment: Inside `((...))` the dollar sign is unnecessary.

Comment: Although `while (( i == 2 ))` is valid syntax in ksh and several other shells, it is not standard.  Since the question is tagged `shell` as well as ksh, the solution ought to be made standard: `while test "$i" = 2 && ...`

Comment: This is my final working version..works on HP, SOL & RHEL. `cat $NASFILE|while [[ $NFS2 != "Completed" ]] && read line; do`